# How to replace plus sign (+) and still not replace %2B using php?

Tags: php

This is my code for test.php

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
$search_value = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_mysqli,$_GET['search_value']);

$search_value_show_text = preg_replace('/\+/', ' ', $search_value);
echo $search_value_show_text; 
?>
```

When i test `www.example.com/test?search_value=%2B+%2B`

It's not echo anything (i mean it's show 3 spaces).

I want to show `+ +`

How can i do ?

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: PHP automatically replaces + signs with spaces and %XX codes with the corresponding ascii characters on `$_GET` parameters. I don't think you have to replace anything here.

Answer (score 3):

You seem not understand what you are doing. Plus sign in url means space, so that's one. Then you replace two other pluses (which are automatically decoded from `%2B` form) with spaces and you end up with three spaces total. Simply do nothing (or use `urldecode()` if needed) with your inpit data and you should be good.

Also you use mysql related ed calls w/o using mysql - thats wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
$search_value = 'www.example.com/test?search_value=%2B+%2B';
$search_value_show_text = preg_replace('/\+/', ' ', $search_value);  
echo $search_value_show_text ."<br/>"; 
$search_value_show_text = preg_replace('/\%2B/', '+', $search_value_show_text);
echo $search_value_show_text;
```

output:

```
www.example.com/test?search_value=%2B %2B
www.example.com/test?search_value=+ +
```